# A binary classification dataset with a 'age' feature whose some of values are missing

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, missing-data, feature-extraction

This classification problem has 300000 tuples and 20 features. I want to use SVM algorithm to solve this problem. The 'age' feature is between 1 and 100, but this feature of some tuples is missing and blank. How should i solve it.

Comment: How many rows are incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This of course depends on the distribution of your missing variable, but I would try imputation - try to fill in the blanks using a mean age value and see what kind of results do you get. One step further would be to create a model predicting age given the other input variables and use that for imputation.

You might also add a variable indicating that a given row has some imputed values - this in some cases yields better training results, as you give your algorithm more information.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to simple imputation by mean as already mentioned by @dratewka, I would suggest trying:

- Imputing the feature using classic imputation mechanisms, like e.g. K nearest neighbour imputation. With this, for a sample `S` with `age` being missing, those K samples that are nearest to `S` are used to derive a suitable value for imputing `age` (with the distance of K neighbours to S measured with all other features).
- After performing the previous step, try your prediction with using `age` and with leaving it out. In case you see that your prediction performance is not influenced by `age`, disregarding this information altogether in the first place might be reasonable as well.